# How to Collect all scores in Blackjack and record games in a table in java?

Tags: java

I need help with creating a table in for my blackjack, that records all games and also shows the average score of all games.I Have my code but im stuck on what to do to fix the code. Here are all the codes that im working with. Here is an example of what the output should look like:[Pic of how output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEARr.png)

```
import java.util.*;
class Blackjack{
      public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Deck d = new Deck();   d.shuffle();
        Hand h = new Hand();
        //Score s = new Score(); //added for bonus
                System.out.println(d);
                System.out.println(d.hit());
                System.out.println( d.decode(d.hit()) );
                h.add(5);
                h.add(10);
                System.out.println(h.display());

        while(true) {
                     System.out.print("Enter (n)ew hand, (h)it, or (q)uit: ");
             Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
             // these variables are for collecting the information for the Score   
             int [] line = new int [5]; //added for Bonus
             int handScore = 0; //added for Bonus
                 char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
                     if (c == 'n' ||  c == 'N') {
                         System.out.println(c);

            h.reset();
                if (d.currentIndex < 51){        
                 int card= d.hit();  h.add(card); 
                 card= d.hit(); h.add(card);
                 h.display(); 
              System.out.println();
                } else if (d.currentIndex > 51) { 
                             System.out.println("--- NO CARDS LEFT ON DECK ---");
                             System.out.println();
                             break;
                        } else {
                     System.out.println("-- NOT ENOUGH CARDS LEFT ON DECK--");
                 System.out.println();
                 break;
            }
             } else if (c == 'h' || c == 'H') {
                             System.out.println(c);
                 if (d.currentIndex < 52){ //must be 52
                int handValue = h.scoreInHand() ;
                if (handValue > 21) {  //already busted
                     System.out.println("--- GET A NEW HAND --- ");    
                     System.out.println();
                } else  if (handValue == 21)  {//already blackjack
                     System.out.println("--- BlackJack --- ");
                     System.out.println();
                } else  if  (h.firstIndex > 4 ) {
                     System.out.println( "-- ALREADY 5 CARDS IN HAND ---");
                     h.display();
                     System.out.println( "--- GET A NEW HAND ---");
                     System.out.println();
                } else if (h.firstIndex == 0) {
                     System.out.println("--- GET A NEW HAND FIRST ---");
                     System.out.println();
                } else {
                          int card= d.hit();  h.add(card); 
                          h.display(); System.out.println();
                }
                 } else { // > or = 52
                  System.out.println("----- NO CARDS LEFT ON DECK -----");
                  System.out.println();
                  break;
                 }//end if (d.firstIndex < 52

                 } else  if (c == 'q' || c == 'Q') {
                             System.out.println(c);
                //same as the  if(c == n), so it can collect the last game.

                break;
             }

          } //while
          //prints the scores of the games the user played while the game was run.
          //System.out.print(s.display());System.out.println(); //added for Bonus
          System.out.println("BYE!");
     }//end main
}


class Hand{
      private int []Hand;
      public int firstIndex;
      Hand(){
           Hand=new int[5];
           for (int i=0; i<Hand.length; i++)
              Hand[i]=-1;
           firstIndex=0;
      }
      public String display(){
             String s="";
             String empty="Hand is empty";
             for (int i=0; i<firstIndex;i++)
                 s=s+" "+decode(Hand[i]);

             if (s.length()==0)
                    s= empty;
             String sih="";
             int sihand= scoreInHand();
             if(sihand>0&&sihand<21)
               sih=""+sihand;
             else if(sihand==21&&firstIndex==2)
               sih="blackjack";
             else if (sihand==21&&firstIndex>2)
               sih=""+sihand;
             else
               sih="BUST";
             System.out.println(s+"\n"+sih);
               return s.trim();
      }
      public void reset(){
           for (int i=0; i<Hand.length;i++)
               Hand[i]=-1;
           firstIndex=0;
      }
      public void add(int card){
            Hand[firstIndex]=card;
            firstIndex++;
      }
      public String decode2(int value){
             String code=""+"HCDS".charAt(value/13)
             +"23456789TJQA".charAt(value%13);
             return code;
      }

      public String decode(int value){

            String[] pattern={"Heart","Clubs","Diamond","Spades"};
            String[] num={"two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king","ace"};
            return num[value%13]+ " of " + pattern[value/13]; 
      }
      public int scoreInHand(){
             int[] s={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10};
             boolean firstAce=true;
             int value=0;
             int sum=0;
             for (int i=0; i<firstIndex; i++)
             {
                  value=Hand[i]%13;
                  if (value==12)
                  {
                        if (firstAce)
                        {
                           value=11;
                           firstAce=false;
                        }
                        else 
                           value=1;

                  }
                  else 
                          value=s[value];



                          sum=sum+value;
               }
               return sum;

         }
         public String toString{
                String s="";
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    if (i<firstIndex)
                        s=s+" |  " + decode2(Hand[i])+"  ";
                    else 
                        s=s+"     ";
                }
                s=s+firstIndex;
                return s;
        }

}//(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11)


class Deck{
      private int[] cards;
      public int currentIndex;
      Deck(){
          currentIndex=0;
          cards=new int[52];
          for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++)
              cards[i]=i;
      }
      public String toString(){
           String s="";
           for (int i=currentIndex;i<cards.length; i++)
           {
              /* s=s+" "+cards[i];*/
              String code=decode(cards[i]);
          s=s+" "+code;   
           }
           return s;
     }
     public String decode(int value)
     {
          String code=""+"HCDS".charAt (value/13)
          +"23456789TJQKA".charAt(value%13);
          return code;
     }
     public void shuffle(){
         int j=0; 
         for (int i=0;i<cards.length; i++)
         {
             j=(int)(52*Math.random());
             swap(i,j);
         }
     }
     public void swap(int i, int j){
        int temp=cards[i];
        cards[i]=cards[j];
        cards[j]=temp;




     }
     public int hit(){
         int i=cards[currentIndex];
         currentIndex++;

         return i;


     }
}


class Score extends Deck{
      private String [] cuts=new String [26];
      private int gfirstIndex;
      Score(){
          cuts=new String[26];
          gfirstIndex=0;
      }
      public void markScore(Hand h, int score)
      {
             String s="";
             char fi;
             String hand=h.toString();
             int firstIndex;
             fi=hand.charAt(hand.length()-1);
             firstIndex=fi-'0';
             hand=hand.substring(0,hand.length()-1);
             s=s+" |  "+(gfirstIndex+1)+(((gfirstIndex+1)<10)?"    ":"     ")|;
             s=s+hand+"     ";
             s=s+"(score="+score+")";
             if (score>21)
                s=s+"(BUSTS)";
             else if (score==21&&firstIndex==2)
                     s=s+"(BLACKJACK)";
             cuts[gfirstIndex]=s;
             gfirstIndex++;
      }
}
```

Comment: @DarkV1: He can't add an image to the question as he doesn't yet have enough rep to do so.

Comment: I did not know that ... Should probably check the rep chart .

Comment: @DarkV1 so do i post the link of the pic that shows what the ouput should look like, as an answer?

Comment: @DarkV1 ok I just posted it